# Установил Linux Mint, проблема с HDMI

Tags: linux, hdmi

Mint не видит HDMI, как добавить эту опцию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте установить драйвера

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/alsa-daily
apt update
apt install oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms
```

Comment: А после установки перезагрузить надо ?

Comment: Да, вам необходимо перезагрузится.

Comment: Попробуйте установить Windows

Comment: @Sergey, если бы ему была нужна венда, он бы не писал этот вопрос.